# Spotify .Net Library

Tags: .net, spotify

Is there a Reliable, working and well documented .Net Spotify Library ?
I have been fiddling with shapotify and libspotify-sharp and no luck so far !

I'm trying to create a new playlist then load it to Spotify Client..
This is what I have tried so far with sharpotify

```
using Sharpotify;  
public JsonResult AddList(string list, string name)
{  
SpotifyConnection connection = new SpotifyConnection(new harpotify.Cache.FileCache(),new TimeSpan(0,1,0));  
string username = "username";  
string password = "password";  
bool result = false;  
try  
{  
 connection.Login(username, password);  
 Sharpotify.Media.Playlist playlist = connection.PlaylistCreate(name);  
 String [] tracks = list.Split(';');  
 for (int i = 0; i < tracks.Length; i++)  
 {  
  if(tracks[i] != string.Empty){  
   Sharpotify.Media.Track t = new Sharpotify.Media.Track(tracks[i]);  
   if (t != null){  
    playlist.Tracks.Add(t);  
   }  
 }  
 }  
 result = true;  
}  
catch (Sharpotify.Exceptions.AuthenticationException ex)  
{  
 connection.Close();  
 result = false;  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
connection.Close();  
result = false;  
}
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could share your *fiddling* results here so that we could see the reason for non succeeding?

Comment: it was only looking at the library and trying different options obviously I don't know what I was doing

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [libspotify.NET](http://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/)? It looks like it's relatively up to date, compared to Sharpotify.

Answer (score 0):

It might not meet your requirements, but you might consider looking at [Sharpotify](http://sharpotify.codeplex.com/).  From its page:

> Sharpotify is a Spotify library in C#. It is based in Jotify and SharPot projects. It is not a libspotify wrapper, It is a full .Net Spotify protocol implementation.

Beware, though, that as of July 2012, the latest release is more than 2 years old; it may no longer be actively maintained.

Comment: I think that sharpotify needs a big update before it can be used again, as it doesn't support any of the current versions of the library. At the very least you need to manually update the API entry points to get it working.

Comment: I have tried that one already and it throws an exception .. The problem is that there is no clear documentation in all the available .Net libraries